# Change css of div wrap when input is clicked and has text typed

Tags: jquery, html, css, input

How do I change the css property of a DIV that is wrapping an input when the input has text typed inside it?  Is this CSS or jquery?

When the client clicks inside or types text inside, I want the DIV wrapping the input to change in background color.

Thank you.

Webpage;  http://www.givemehope.com/home.htm

```
<div id="home_find_wrapper">
   <a class="home_find" href="#"></a>
   <div class="home_search"><input name="company_name" type="text" value=""></div>
   <div class="home_search_go"></div>
</div>


#home_find_wrapper              {width:351px;height:100px;top:715px;left:71px;position:absolute;z-index:999;float:left;transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.home_search                    {width:250px;height:100px;float:left;background:#FFF;opacity:.5;transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.home_search_go                 {width:100px;height:100px;float:left;background:#FFF;opacity:.5;margin-left:1px;transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;}
.home_find                      {width:100px;height:100px;float:left;background: url('img/home_find.png') no-repeat;opacity:1;position:absolute;top:0;left:248px;transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;} 
#home_find_wrapper:hover        
     .home_search, #home_find_wrapper:hover          .home_search_go {cursor:pointer;background:#FFF;opacity:.7}

.home_search input              {width:248px;height:75px;padding-top:10px;line-height:75px;background:transparent;float:left;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;border:0;font-size: 3.5em;font-family:'open_sansextrabold';color:#4D4D4D}
```

Comment: This may help: http://css-tricks.com/improved-current-field-highlighting-in-forms/

Comment: Interesting question, I guess this is possible only with JS, but maybe somebody will surprise us :D

Comment: here is my webpage:  www.givemehope.com/home.htm

Comment: the `:focus` pseudo selector can help with this, but typically anything involving modifying a parent element will involve some JS/jQuery

Comment: Exactly, there's no parent selector in CSS yet.

Answer (score 1):

How about attaching `keyup` on the input and adding a CSS class to the parent div?

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().addClass('focus');

    if (!$this.val().length) {
        $this.parent().removeClass('focus');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kgss/

Comment: But this is adding a class to the input.  I need this to add class to a div wrapping the input.  not the input.

Comment: @Erik Nope. `$this.parent()` gets the parent of `this` - in this case the parent of `input`. Added some comments to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kgss/4/

Answer (score 0):

My version:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<input type="text" id="test" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cambio{ background : red }
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").keyup(function(){
   if(this.value != "")
   {
     $("#wrapper").addClass('cambio');
   }
    else
    {
        $("#wrapper").removeClass('cambio');
    }
});
});
```

EDITED:

For your specific version of the code, you have to remove the active class and then add de nonactive class, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#idnumber").keyup(function(){
if(this.value != "")
{
    $(".home_search").removeClass('nonactive');
    $(".home_search").addClass('active');
}
else
{
    $(".home_search").removeClass('active');
    $(".home_search").addClass('nonactive');
}
});
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/8kF3u/

Comment: if the client delete's the text inside the input, can I remove the class and put the wrapper back to its original state??

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Its interesting.  When I type something in the search field it works.  But when i delete the text inside, the css is not removed.  www.givemehope.com/home.htm

Comment: I can't access your site...i'm in my job and the content of your website is blocked by Proxy Avoidance

Comment: You have the best solution.  All I need is to remove the class when the input field is cleared.

Comment: Can you mail me your code to robert.rozas.n@gmail.com please?

Answer (score 0):

Give the div an id, so you can reference it. Then use the onfocus and onblur events of the input element to call respective functions that change the style of the div.

Declare the "active" style of the div in a class, then have the onfocus and onblur event handler functions set/unset that class to the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="inputBox">
   <input type="text" onfocus="activateBox()" onblur="deactivateBox()" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxActive{
   background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
box = document.getElementById("inputBox");
activeClass = "boxActive";

function activateBox(){
   box.className = activeClass;
}

function deactivateBox(){
    box.className = "";
}
```

This only makes sense, if your div style (when active) is more complex. If you know exactly what's going on with the style of the div, you can set it with plain JavaScript, like "box.style.backgroundColor = 'red';".

If your input element is a direct child of the div, you can also reference the div with the parentNode property.

Comment: It should help to leave out the "var" in front of the "box" and "activeClass" variable declarations, to make them global. + add parenthesis in the onfocus/onblur attributes (in the HTML for the input). I have now changed these things in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do yo mean something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/teune/dm6Hm/37/

HTML

```
<input class="myinput">
<span>Can I have your name?</span>

<p>Click input to focus.</p>
<input class="myinput">
<span>Can I have your name 2?</span>

<p>Click input to focus.</p>
<input class="myinput">
<span>Can I have your name 3?</span>

<p>Click input to focus.</p>
```

JS

```
$(".myinput").change(function (e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if ($test.val() != "JohnDoe") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $test.css("background-color", "#FF0000").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: what about the case where text has been entered? And won't this build up multiple blur handlers if the input receives and loses focus multiple times?